# Proving that there exists $\delta > 0$ such that: $d\left(e_i,\sum_{j\neq i} \lambda_je_j\right)\geq\delta$

Tags: functional-analysis

I'm having some trouble with the following exercise:

> Let $e_1,...,e_n$ ($n\geq 2$) be linear independent vectors of a normed space $E$. Prove that there is a $\delta>0$ such that, for any $i=1,...,n$ and $\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n\in \mathbb C$, we have that: $$d\left(e_i,\sum_{j\neq i} \lambda_je_j\right)\geq\delta$$

I tried using Riesz's lemma to prove this but I wans't able to conclude this. How can this be done?

Comment: Finite dimensional subspaces are closed. If $d(e_i,\sum_{j\neq i}e_j)=0$ for some $i$, then $e_i\in \operatorname{span}(e_j:j\neq i\}$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For each $i\in\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$, let $E_i$ be the space spanned by all $e_j$'s with $j\ne i$. Then $\dim E_i<\infty$, and therefore, $E_i$ is closed. Furthermore, $e_i\notin E_i$, from which it follows that $d(e_i,E_i)>0$. Now, take$$\delta=\min\bigl\{d(e_i,E_i)\mid i\in\{1,2,\ldots,n\}\bigr\}.$$Can you prove that this $\delta$ will do?

Comment: I can. Thank you